# Does anything limit the number of tests you can make at the Market?

Tags: torchbearer

In the Town Phase, when using the Market to buy an item, you make a Resources test (optionally spending any amount of loot for extra dice) against the Obstacle listed for that item. On a success, you gain the item. On a failure, nothing happens.

So for an Ob 1 item (say, a torch), if you have Resources 1, **can you just shop for the item repeatedly until you succeed?** Nothing in the rules appears to prevent this or impose any limit on how many attempts you get. In particular there's no Lifestyle cost for using the Market.

The naive reading of this is that once you have Resources 1, you can make unlimited shopping attempts, giving you unlimited successful and failed tests, which maxes out your Resources very quickly. I find it hard to believe that that's intentional.

Another possibility would be that (since you could in theory keep rolling until you succeed), you can simply acquire any item with Ob <= your Resources without rolling a test. This would actually make a lot of sense, since low-Ob items need to be easy to replenish*. And you wouldn't accumulate successful tests this way, so you'd only advance Resources if you were spending loot dice to buy things beyond your current means, and that makes sense as a progression mechanic. The only problem is that the rules don't seem to say this anywhere.

Alternatively, if you fail to buy an item once, are you barred from trying again? This would also make some amount of sense, except that (1) it's way too easy to dig yourself into an inescapable hole the first time you enter Town, and (2) the rules don't say this, either.

I'm finding Torchbearer's rules difficult to navigate, so it's entirely possible I'm missing something.

(I'm using the first edition, 2015 printing.)

*Or else you get into a death spiral where you can't afford torches or rations, and so you can't really adventure, and any money you do manage to scrape together gets eaten by Lifestyle costs.

Comment: Just to confirm, this is the first edition of Torchbearer? A second edition recently completed its kickstart but I don't know how much of that is publicly available yet. My first edition is from 2013.

Comment: @Glazius First edition, second printing, 2015.

Comment: Maybe we should make a "torcherbearer-1e" tag, and reallocated the existing questions to have that tag instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Resources is an Ability. Most rules for its use are in the Abilities chapter.

Specifically, these sections on p.28 and 29 of the hardcover indicate what should be happening here: (They're recapitulated in more GM-facing terms in the GM's Ability and Skill Factors section starting on p. 134, but as this question is asked from a playerly perspective, I'm quoting the playerly rules.)

> **Taxing Resources**
>
> If the GM wishes, when you fail a Resources test, instead of the standard conditions, he may reduce your character's Resources by the margin of failure. Like Nature, this reduction of dice is called tax (though is is not recovered the way taxed Nature is).
>
> After tax, Resources may be advanced as normal.
>
> **Treasure and Cash** [...]
>
> Treasure and cash dice can be spent even when Resources is 0. Once used to augment a Resources test, any treasure or cash dice added are expended and the loot is removed from your inventory. [...] Spending cash, loot, or treasure on a roll insulates you from tax due to that roll. Each die worth of treasure spent will absorb one point of tax.
>
> **0 Resources**
>
> If Resources is depleted to zero, the character may not make Resources tests unless he uses cash or treasure dice. You may not use persona points to augment the 0 ability unless you spend cash or treasure.

You exit character creation with as much common gear as you want and can carry (from the table on p. 18) but 0 Resources, the idea being that you've spent everything to outfit yourself for this trip and it's going to pay off, right?

For the sake of example, because I've seen this "tax" thing confound people before, let's suppose it does go well, and you come back with, among other things, a quantity of gold coins (pack 1, +2D) and silver coins (pack 1, +1D). You're at Resources 0, so in order to buy anything at all you need to spend some of this. So let's go to market!

You want some preserved rations (Ob 2), so you plunk down your gold coins and hope. You get a 1 and a 3, of course. You have failed the test by a margin of 2 and your gold coins are spent and lost. However, the GM can opt to tax your Resources and get you the item anyway - taxing Resources is equivalent to imposing a Condition in that they both give you what you were after from the test. Because you have 2 dice of treasure, you can ignore up to 2 points of Resources tax, so you effectively suffer no tax, which is a good thing at Resources 0.

Something to observe right now - *you can always buy something with treasure dice equal to its Ob*. You cannot possibly incur more tax this way than the amount of treasure dice you spent, so the tax won't hit your Resources. (The GM could always choose not to impose tax and instead give you a Condition, which would get you the rations; or a Twist, which wouldn't -- although in practice, purchasing things with sufficient money at a market isn't likely to merit those alternatives.) However, look to p.104:

> To advance your Resources 0 to 1, you need one passed test using cash, loot, or treasure dice. [...] If your Resources advances in town, you may not advance it again until the next town phase.

You may want to spend more money than something is worth to get that Resources pass. Or maybe buy something cheap and hope to get lucky?

Dang ol' goblins made a shirt out of your treasure sack (Ob 1) anyhow, so you drop some silver on one. The die comes up a 5! Great! The silver is spent and gone, but now your Resources is 1 instead of 0 because you've passed a Resources test! Though it's not going to go any higher this town phase.

Flush with hubris, now you try to buy some torches at Ob 1, toss your single Resource die, and it comes up a 2, the traitor. Well, your margin of failure is 1, so the GM can tax you back down to 0. And now you're stuck there, and have to pay for your lifestyle somehow. Hope you have more treasure dice that you decided not to use for whatever reason! At least the rules indicate that you can recover one point of tax since it resets your advancement.

For expensive purchases, you (can also/may have no other choice than to) spend fewer treasure dice than the Ob, in hopes that you hit some successes and the treasure you've spent is enough to absorb the tax so it doesn't hit your Resources. If you don't have enough Resources for it, the GM can pull out a twist or a condition instead, and the twist is likely to be some bill collectors.

The upshot of this is that, yes, you could potentially find yourself without the means to purchase torches or rations or pay for your lifestyle. This is intended. Unlike, say, members of the Mouse Guard, you are not acknowledged and important members of your society. You had to sell everything you owned to grub for treasure in a desolate ruin. If that doesn't work out, you have no backup plan; perhaps the debt collectors can dictate one to you.

Comment: So to sum up, every time you fail the check, you either gain a condition or lose Resources to tax (or else you're spending loot/coin, which is exempt from Resources tax, but that's finite). Is that about right?

Comment: “If a Resources test is failed, you can use the standard condition or twist rules for failure or you can use a **special condition** for Resources tests called tax.” Page 134, emphasis mine.

Comment: @MarkWells More or less. In the interests of clarity and usefulness I've expanded the spending section a bit. Does it help?

Comment: @Glazius I appreciate the additional detail, yes.